# Are my questions simply bad/in violation of rules of the site?

Tags: discussion

I've recently noticed that my recent questions do not receive much attention / are not answered even within one or two days. For example, for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839683/interpreting-displaystyle-frac-lambdac-mu1-in-steady-state-solution-of-m) I had to put a bounty on the question to get any sort of response, even a comment, after 12 days of waiting. I do not understand this, as the question got 2 upvotes before starting the bounty. Is it that the question was too basic? Or is it just bad? But then, why?

Again, for [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850358/how-do-i-understand-this-aspect-of-shapley-values), I believe those are pretty valid questions that might pop up when doing Shapley values for the first time. I understand that I can make tiny edits to the question which will push it to the Active page, but I do not want to abuse my editing rights . I also do not think that I should have to spend my reputation (as bounty) to get any sort of answer on my question.

So I sincerely would ask the community to point out any mistakes or rule-violations in my questions.

Comment: The second question certainly needs more focus and should be closed, as it stands. They would be fine as separate questions anyway, and you can always add a link at the bottom to the other parts to help add context.

Comment: To second what JonathanZ said below I have no idea what "Shapley values" are either

Answer (score 10):

Since you're asking for feedback: Looking at just the two linked questions, I'd say that they're a bit obscure, and they're a bit nebulous. Neither is actually bad, or in violation of any rules - you didn't get any down votes.

But "....doing Shapley values for the first time"? I've never heard of a Shapely value, and your question didn't make them sound like something I'd like to investigate. Again, that's not bad, and lots of questions are like that, but it's why I'd just skip past that question. Also, you're asking for lots of explanation and motivation (asking "Why?"), and those take extra effort to write up, another disincentive. And insights like those only come with longer exposure to a subject, and a broader view of multiple possible approaches. Asking for such responses further limits the pool of possible respondents.

Questions relating to core subjects (calc, real & complex analysis, topology, basic algebra) get tons of activity. Yours lie outside of those, and are getting about the level of attention I'd expect. If you want more, do some bounties. Heck, you're above 5k - that's a level where I expect people to stop worrying about hoarding rep, and thinking about what's best for the community.

I will say that I've been trying to be better about up voting questions that aren't in my areas, but are well written, and yours are examples of those. Thanks for those contributions, and I hope you'll keep at it.